# setTimeOut not working as expected in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, settimeout

For some reason, the `setTimeOut` variable in my function does not work. I have tried a few different strategies, but none have worked. Basically, I am attempting to set a delay before the audio plays. Below is both my JS and HTML code.

```
function song(musicfile) {
  $('#result').html("<audio autoplay=\"true\"><source src=" + musicfile + " type=\"audio/mpeg\" /></audio>");
  setTimeout(song, 10000);
}
```

```html
<img class="playbutton1 center-block" src="play.png" onclick="song('pretender.m4a');">
```

Comment: Why is `song` quoted?

Comment: I removed the quotes. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Try this: setTimeout(function(){ song(musicfile); }, 10000);

Comment: Your call to `song` doesn't pass any parameters. Also, if you're trying to delay the call your logic is wrong. You need to create the `audio` element *inside* the `setTimeout()` call, and not recursively call `song()` every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there's no delay. Someone clicks the image, you immediately inject the `<audio>` element, and then set a delay.

What you need is to `setTimeout(function_that_injects_the_element, 10000)`.

```
function song(musicfile) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#result').html("<audio autoplay=\"true\"><source src=" + musicfile + " type=\"audio/mpeg\" /></audio>");
  }, 10000);
}
```

I might suggest also removing any existing audio elements, or at least stopping them if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JQuery. Thanks for adding some background as to how I mismanaged the code's hierarchy.

Comment: This is vanilla JS stuff -- `setTimeout` is built in. All jQuery's doing is the actual insertion of the element.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery call should be inside the setTimeout

```
function song(musicfile) {

  setTimeout(function(){$('#result').html("<audio autoplay=\"true\"><source src=" + musicfile + " type=\"audio/mpeg\" /></audio>");}, 10000);
}
```